# Adding account to android device running android version 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-account, accounts

Had this old phone lying around. I thought I re-purpose it for some IoT stuff. It an old Micromax A50 Ninja (running ginger bread 2.3.6). I want to make an app on this device that communicates with arduino. However, I cannot sign into the device. I re-checked with my credentials else where, and they checkout to be fine. But on this device, the sign-in still fails.

Is this because the OS is outdated? Well, can I do anything on this phone, now that this is the state of the device os?

Comment: "Secondly" is totally off-topic here (this site is for end-users, not for development issues) – so I took the freedom to remove that part. Furthermore,  this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). As for the remaining part: Why? You don't even need any account to use the device. Have you tried a factory reset? Being that ancient, there's no danger of encountering "factory reset protection" (FRP); simply boot into recovery and do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be to add an app password: https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords